# Scala match any enum value in a case statement

Tags: scala

I have a scala enumeration defined:

```
object SalesChannelType extends scala.Enumeration {
  type SalesChannelType = Value
  val SALES_CHANNEL_1, SALES_CHANNEL_2 = Value
}

class SalesChannelType extends TypeReference[SalesChannelType.type]
```

Now I would like to write a match statement that in a single case matches any enumeration value, something like:

```
SalesChannelType.SALES_CHANNEL_1 match {
    case SalesChannelType => println(_)
    case _ => println("specified sales channel does not exist")
```

The idea is for the first case statement to print the sales channel if it is defined in the enumeration. Otherwise, the second case statement should be invoked. Currently the code above wont compile with the error `Pattern type is incompatible with expected type, found SalesChannel.type required SalesChannel.Value`

Comment: If your program is decently typed no non existent sales channel can reach that pattern match. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah you make a good point, this is a unnecessary match statement. Still wondering if its possible though?

Comment: You can make a [custom pattern/extractor](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html).

Comment: I think you're looking for `case s: SalesChannelType.Value =>  ...` - that would match any of the enum's values

Comment: if you are interested in read a bit more about scala enums: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/

Comment: @TzachZohar Please don't put answers into comments. Especially when there are a lot of them and easy to miss that one is actually an answer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyRomanov - absolutely right, wasn't sure this is actually an answer, at a second glance it obviously is what the OP was looking for. Posted as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for (although @Jasper-M's comment is correct - if program is decently typed, this is useless):

```
SalesChannelType.SALES_CHANNEL_1 match {
  case s: SalesChannelType.Value => println(s)
  case _ => println("specified sales channel does not exist")
}
```